# How do I mount a volume in a docker container in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using `.gitlab-ci.yml` and docker as a GitLab CI runner on an Android project. At the end of the test run, `gradlew` saves test results in xml and html under the build directory:

```
Finished generating test XML results (0.001 secs) into: /builds/org/project/sdk/build/test-results/release
 Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.002 secs) into: /builds/org/project/sdk/build/reports/tests/release
```

I'd like to have access to these files, but the [documentation](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) doesn't mention how to mount a volume like one would with `docker run -v <path>:/builds/org/...`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would advice against mounting volumes from the host for your CI.
If you really want to, you have to configure the runner accordingly (`config.toml`).
If you are using `shared` runners you never know on what system a particular build is going to be executed.

I think the better solution would be to define the test-results as [artifacts](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/builds/artifacts.html).

That way, the test-results are available for older builds and not only the latest build.

Below you can find the configuration (`config.toml`) of my runner I use for building docker-images. You can replace `/var/run/docker.sock` by the directory you want your build-results to end up in.

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Docker"
  url = "https://mygitlab/ci"
  token = "mytoken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

Comment: I realised after reading the gitlab-ci.yml documentation a little more carefully that I was on the wrong path. Using _artifacts_ as suggested by @mgansler worked for me.

Comment: @Martin I installed my gitlab-runner on k8s using the Gitlab 11.9.8 - through the K8s integration UI. Now after installation, I can't seem to modify the configuration of the runner. I used kubeadm to set up my k8s cluster. I want to mount /var/run/docker.sock from the host to the container where i'm building my code.

Comment: an example of how artifacts can be used to access a file generated during gitlab pipeline execution, even if the pipeline fails: https://juristr.com/blog/2020/10/upload-failed-artifacts-gitlab/