# How to make docker run -v work on my local gitlab-runner like it does on GitLab shared runners?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, mount, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to find the settings I need to add to my self-hosted `gitlab-runner` in order to achieve the following: In a repository containing a `dir/script.py` I'm running

```
services:
  - docker:dind

main:
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker run -i -v $(pwd)/dir:/mnt python:3 ls -la /mnt
```

with a GitLab shared runner which shows that `dir/script.py` has successfully been mounted into the container and is present as `/mnt/script.py`.

If I use my self-hosted `gitlab-runner` the directory is empty. I tried adding `--privileged` to `docker run` in `.gitlab.yml` as well as in the runner configuration in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`.

I'm pretty sure the mounted directory is empty inside the container because the [mount path refers to the path on the host](https://forums.docker.com/t/mounting-a-volume-not-working-with-running-docker-in-docker/25775) (see also [Docker in Docker cannot mount volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381322/docker-in-docker-cannot-mount-volume)). However, there seems to be a way for GitLab's shared runners to deal with that and I want to find and adopt this way to my self-hosted runner.

I'm running `gitlab-runner` and providing Docker-in-Docker by running the `systemd` unit

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker network create --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 gitlab-runner-net
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker run -d --name gitlab-dind --privileged --restart always --network gitlab-runner-net -v /var/lib/docker -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR= docker:19.03-dind --storage-driver=overlay2
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name gitlab-runner --restart always --network gitlab-runner-net --dns 8.8.8.8 -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -e DOCKER_HOST=tcp://gitlab-dind:2375 gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop gitlab-runner
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop gitlab-dind
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm gitlab-runner
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm gitlab-dind
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker network rm gitlab-runner-net
```

(extract) and by adding

```
host = "tcp://gitlab-dind:2375"
volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
extra_hosts = ["gitlab-dind:172.25.0.2"]
```

to every runner section of the `config.toml`. This has been inspired by https://medium.com/@tonywooster/docker-in-docker-in-gitlab-runners-220caeb708ca. The setup allows to use `docker build` inside `.gitlab-ci.yml` and share the Docker cache between builds.

[How do I mount a volume in a docker container in .gitlab-ci.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004369/how-do-i-mount-a-volume-in-a-docker-container-in-gitlab-ci-yml) suggests using artifacts which is not an option since I want to test this scenario.

Comment: Don't have an answer since I'd want to test it, but have you looked at the shared runner settings? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#configtoml
another consideration is that the medium article is from 2+ years ago so a lot has changed especially with dind 19.03+ so I recommend checking out the dind part of the runner docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor

Comment: @Arty-chan Thanks for your useful input. I updated by dind container to 19.03.1 without any change in the result. I didn't find anything in the config.toml of shared runners that I'd say might explain why mounting directories on shared runners works flawlessly. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor is a neat workaround, but I'd rather use shared runners than adjust my code to work on the CI with my self-hosted runner.